# receiving varied assessments at the hands of

Tags: british-english, syntactic-analysis

Is there anything wrong or just clunky about the following sentence:

Consequently, a heated debate ensued on the nature of the monument, receiving varied assessments at the hands of different scholars.

I'm not sure about the gerund but I don't want to use a relative clause either.
Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is quite confusing as to what *receiving various assessments at the hands of different scholars* modifies.
"Traditional grammar" says that it should modify the closest reasonable noun, which would be *nature* or *monument*. (See Purdue Owl's [webpage](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/participles.html#:%7E:text=A%20participle%20is%20a%20verbal%20ending%20in%20%2Ding%20(present),%2For%20complement(s).) on this.) However, to me it reads like it should modify *debate*, which makes utter nonsense of the sentence. This seems to show that "traditional grammar" doesn't know what it's talking about. (This question as to what participles actually modify in English may be treated better in scholarly grammar books, like CGEL.) From the meaning, the participle is clearly intended to modify *nature* or *monument*.

If you want to use a participle but want it to modify a different word, one way to do it is reorder the elements of the sentence. Since I can't really tell what the participle is supposed to modify, this is a wild guess as to the intended meaning on my part:

> The monument, receiving various assessments at the hands of different scholars, provoked heated debate over its nature.

Reordering the elements of a sentence can really disrupt the flow of a paragraph, and if it does in this case, I would encourage you to just use a relative clause.

Comment: It's simply not possible for a monument (or any inanimate object) to be the recipient of assessment. ("Here, monument, this is my report on you.") Instead, assessment reports are given to people or committees, in this case a debating committee. Contrary to saying that the debating committee (or "the debate") receiving assessments is nonsense, I think the monument receiving it is nonsense.

Comment: @Jason: That is an interpretation that rejects any use of non-absolutely-literal language. Why not just do away with Shakespeare while you're at it?

Comment: @Robusto No, it's contextual if something is figurative or literal. See my comments under the question itself.

Comment: BTW, +1. I don't see why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: Could the word *received* itself be the troublemaker? If so, rewording to "monument, which received" clarifies whose face got slapped, but doesn't solve this core issue.

Comment: Yes, *received* should be replaced with *...monument, which was the object of ...* or the like.

Comment: *Scholars' opinions on the monument varied wildly, leading to [a] heated debate.*

Comment: Or, taking the original sentence more literally, *A heated debate followed, **in which** the monument was subjected to a variety of scholarly appraisals*.